# How to import and use Jasypt - Java Library

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to use ["Jasypt"](http://www.jasypt.org/) in my Java project, but I'm having some troubles. I'm using NetBeans IDE.

I download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasypt/files/jasypt/jasypt%201.9.0/jasypt-1.9.0-dist.zip/download) file, then I **right clicked on my project -> Properties -> Library -> Add Jar/Folder**. So, I add the folder of Jasypt (uncompressed, called "jasypt-1.9.0").

I can see the Jasypt folder in my project now, but when I try to use it, I have troubles. When I try to instantiate the "BasicPasswordEncryptor" (following my code) I got an error.

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicPasswordEncryptor;

public class GerenciarConexao {

    public boolean Login(String nome, String senha){

        BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
        // (later will add the code)
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the "inline error":

```
package org.jasypt.util.text does not exist
```

**If I tr to build my project, I got the following error:**

```
C:\Users\silvio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LocusView\src\control\GerenciarConexao.java:6: error: package org.jasypt.util.text does not exist
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor;

C:\Users\silvio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LocusView\src\control\GerenciarConexao.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
            BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
      symbol:   class BasicPasswordEncryptor
      location: class GerenciarConexao

C:\Users\silvio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LocusView\src\control\GerenciarConexao.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
            BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
      symbol:   class BasicPasswordEncryptor
      location: class GerenciarConexao
    3 errors
```

About this import, I don't know why is this path, I just find a question about Jasypt in StackOverflow and copy/paste the import to my project - I didn't find a easy guide that tell me how to install/use the Jasypt.

Thanks friends, waiting for answers - and sorry about my nonsense.

Comment: My question was edited, review the code before answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BasicPasswordEncryptor does not exist use BasicTextEncryptor instead